# Extract key value pair in Spark SQL where the key is a URL and value is a string

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-databricks

I have a JSON object as below

```
"data": [
    {
        "keyId": <guid>,
        "keyContext":
            "keyContextValue":
                "https://access.dummy.com/training/date/last_modified_dtm":"2024-02-01 17:02:41",
                "https://access.dummy.com/training/id/training_id":"300",
                "https://access.dummy.com/training/name/training_name":"Dummy Training"
    }
]
```

I am able to extract the values until KeyContext:KeyContextValue Array using get_json_object function in Spark SQL. But My requirement is to extract the actual values in this array to show as below.

| keyId | last_modified_dtm | training_id | training_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2024-02-01 | 300 | Dummy Training |

Since the key is a URL, I am not sure how to extract the value. Can someone please assist on how to use Spark SQL to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the `simple` logic. tried in differently.

All you need is

- Schema to extract required columns from json object.

  `'data ARRAY<STRUCT<keyContext: STRUCT<keyContextValue: MAP<STRING, STRING>>, keyId: STRING>>'`
- Schema for final output columns.

  `'last_modified_dtm timestamp, training_id int, training_name string'`

And then make use of built in functions like

- `inline` to flatten array
- `from_json` to extract columns from json
- `from_csv` to convert desired output.

```
SELECT    
    inline(
        transform(
            from_json(
                data, 
                'data ARRAY<STRUCT<keyContext: STRUCT<keyContextValue: MAP<STRING, STRING>>, keyId: STRING>>'
            ).data.keyContext.keyContextValue,
            e -> from_csv(
                concat_ws(',', map_values(e)),
                'last_modified_dtm timestamp, training_id int, training_name string'
            )
        )
    )
FROM <table_name>
```